# Get URL avatar of a specific person Mybb

Tags: mybb

I would like to get the url of the avatar of a member having only the nickname.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($mybb->user['username'] == $username)
{
    $avatar = $mybb->user['avatar'];
}
else
{
    $query = $db->simple_select('users', 'avatar', "username = ".$db->escape_string($username)."'", array('LIMIT' => 1));
    $avatar = $db->fetch_field($query, 'avatar');
}
```

Where $username is the username of the user and the returned $avatar is the URL of the avatar.

Or, by using the inbuilt function:

```
if($mybb->user['username'] == $username)
{
    $avatar = $mybb->user['avatar'];
}
elseif(get_user_by_username($username, array('exists' => true)) !== False)
{
    $user = get_user_by_username($username, array('fields' => array('avatar'))); // Add other fields you want to the fields array.
    $avatar = $user['avatar'];
}
else
{
    error('Invalid user');
}
```

---

Also post at the [MyBB Community Forums](http://community.mybb.com) as that is where the MyBB Group provide official support.

Comment: So we just need to get in the db and take the data, i thought mybb has his own functions..

Comment: Added the use of the inbuilt get_user_by_username function to the answer. - Which should answer your question. ;)